# "Restricting" records in a many-to-many relationship - Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, many-to-many, ms-access-2007

I've been tasked with building a quote-creation database for a set of users and I'm having trouble figuring out something. I've determined I'll need a many-to-many relationship for just about every table I create and I'll explain why..

*Note: I do not need to store these quotes, I only need to give users the ability to create quotes and print them

My main table, Boats, will have many records (We'll say Boat1, Boat2, Boat3, etc...)
One of my other tables, Motors, will have many motors (Motor1, Motor2, Motor3, etc...)

I'm assuming I'll need a join table to get these to marry up on a form. My problem is this:

*If Boat1 can only use Motor1 and Motor3, but Boat2 can use Motor1, Motor2, Motor3, and Boat3 can only use Motor3*... How do I determine this?

I've thought of having two columns in Motors, Motor_Desc & Boat_Desc, but then we're talking **thousands** of records. I don't know how to proceed :(

*edit 5-30-2013*

Table design for this question:

**Boats**

- Boat_ID
- Boat_Part
- Boat_Desc

**Motors**

- Motor_ID
- Motor_Part
- Motor_Desc

Answer (score 0):

I don't think databases will support DB level support for row-dependent logic for whether a new entry is valid or not.

You can have a Boat/Motor valid table AND a Boat/Motor use table. Compare against the validity table before constructing the use table.

Comment: I won't have any entries. These tables will hold previously entered data (entered by an administrator), then an end user will only configure based on that data within the tables.

IE: I want to order Boat1, which can only use Motor1 and Motor2. So I choose Motor1. Then, since I chose Boat1, I can only get Trailer2, Trailer5, or Trailer6. 

It sounds like the only way would be to have each table have the Boat1 in a column...

Comment: how is the validity data stored now? I am confused how you know which relationships are valid 9 and which are not if it is not currently stored.

Comment: There is no data stored yet. I'm still in the planning stages of building the database. In the end, I want it to work in the same way the Dell site would work when ordering a PC. I choose option A, which means I can only choose Option A accessories.

Comment: Then you need to create a mapping table for valid combinations since it would be a many to many relationship which can determining what can be shown. When you are retrieving, just perform a join on the validity table to get all the values.